# How do I rename and overwrite part of file name in Bash at the same time?

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have multiple JS files in folder, for example, **foo.js**, **this_is_foo.js**, **foo_is_function.js**.

I want to append a number which is **passed as parameter** in front of extension ".js", such as **foo.1.js**, **this_is_foo.1.js**, **foo_is_function.1.js**

I write a script to append a number successfully the first time, but if I run the script twice, it does not overwrite the first number but append right after that.

Actual result: **foo.js** --> **foo.1.js** (1st run) -->  **foo.1.2.js** (2nd run).

Expected result: **foo.js** --> **foo.1.js** (1st run) --> **foo.2.js** (2nd run).

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
param=$1
for file in *.js; do
    ext="${file##*.}";
    filename="${file%.*}";
    mv "$file" "${filename}.${param}.${ext}";
done
```

How can I do that? I want to write pure bash script, not to use any tools.

Comment: What do you want to happen in a directory that already contains `foo.js`, `foo1.js`, `foo2.js`, `...` `foo32.js` and you pass in `1`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin They will be foo.1.js, foo1.1.js, foo2.1.js, foo32.1.js.

Comment: Okay, my bad, I meant if you had `foo.js`, `foo.1.js`, `foo.2.js`, `...`, `foo.32.js` such that when you pass, e.g. `1` the file was already present. Do you want to set `foo.js` as `foo.1.js` and then increment the remaining numbers by `+1` to avoid the conflict? What happens if the new filenames already exists?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh, I understand your question. Inititally, there are not any duplicated files, for example, foo.js, my_foo.js. In the beginning, if there are two files in the folder such as foo.js and foo.1.js (I mean the original names), it is accepted that the result will be foo.1.js and foo.1.1.js. But when I run the script twice and the parameter is 2, it should be foo.2.js and foo.1.2.js.
The parameters can be anything, a number, a character, not neccessarily an incremental counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing the rename you can check if what is after the last dot in filename (`${filename%.*}`) is numeric. If so switch that with param instead of appending a new param

Since you are writing that you want to use pure bash I assume that it is ok to change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
param=$1
for file in *.js; do
    ext="${file##*.}";
    filename="${file%.*}";

    # Check if what is after the last dot in filename is numeric
    # Then assume that it should be switched to param
    if [[ ${filename##*.} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        mv "$file" "${filename%.*}.${param}.${ext}"

    ## Else add param
    else
        mv "$file" "${filename}.${param}.${ext}"
    fi  
done
```

Testrun

```
$> touch a.js && find -type f -name *.js && \
 ./test.sh 1 && find -type f -name *.js && \
 ./test.sh 2 && find -type f -name *.js

./a.js
./a.1.js
./a.2.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extended globbing to match an optional `.` (the one before the number) and any amount of digits before the `.js` suffix.

I also added the `.` to the `$param` variable if the variable is non-empty. This way you can call the script without parameter and `.<number>` is removed instead of added/changed.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob # enable extended globbing

param=$1
if [ -n "$param" ]; then
    param=.${param} # add prefix `.`
fi

for file in *.js; do
    newfile=${file%%?(.)*([0-9]).js}${param}.js
    if [ "$file" = "$newfile" ]; then
        echo "skipping \"${file}\", no need to rename"
    elif [ -f "$newfile" ]; then
        echo "skipping \"$file\", file \"$newfile\" already exists"
    else
        mv "$file" "$newfile"
    fi
done
```

Usage:

```
./script.sh 1 # change suffix to `.1.js`
./script.sh 2 # change suffix to `.2.js`
./script.sh   # change suffix to `.js`
```

Comment: If `foo.js` and `foo1.js`, then does calling `./script.sh 1` mean `foo.js` is left unchanged?

Comment: `foo.js` would have overwritten `foo.1.js`. I added a check to not overwrite existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Posix compliant solution, which allows you to keep using `/bin/sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
param=$1
for file in *.js; do
    ext="${file##*.}";
    filename="${file%.*}";
    [ -z "${filename##*.##*[!0-9]*}" ] && mv "$file" "${filename}.${param}.${ext}" || mv "$file" "${filename%.*}.${param}.${ext}"
done
```

Testrun

```
$> touch a.js && find -type f -name *.js && \
 ./test.sh 1 && find -type f -name *.js && \
 ./test.sh 2 && find -type f -name *.js

./a.js
./a.1.js
./a.2.js
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

counter=1

for file in *.js; do
  if [[ $file =~ (^[^\.]+)(\.js)$ ]]; then
    mv -v "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.$counter${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  elif [[ $file =~ (^[^\.]+)\.([[:digit:]]+)(\.js)$ ]]; then
    first=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    counter=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    extension=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    ((counter++))
    mv -v "$file" "$first.$counter$extension"
  fi
done
```

---

In action.

```
mkdir -p /tmp/123 && cd /tmp/123
```

```
touch foo.js
touch this_is_foo.js
touch this_is_foucntion.js
```

First run

```
./myscript
```

Output

```
renamed 'foo.js' -> 'foo.1.js'
renamed 'this_is_foo.js' -> 'this_is_foo.1.js'
renamed 'this_is_foucntion.js' -> 'this_is_foucntion.1.js'
```

Second run.

```
renamed 'foo.1.js' -> 'foo.2.js'
renamed 'this_is_foo.1.js' -> 'this_is_foo.2.js'
renamed 'this_is_foucntion.1.js' -> 'this_is_foucntion.2.js'
```

Third run.

```
renamed 'foo.2.js' -> 'foo.3.js'
renamed 'this_is_foo.2.js' -> 'this_is_foo.3.js'
renamed 'this_is_foucntion.2.js' -> 'this_is_foucntion.3.js'
```

Using a `for loop`

```
for i in {1..5}; do ./script.sh ; done
```

Output

```
renamed 'foo.js' -> 'foo.1.js'
renamed 'this_is_foo.js' -> 'this_is_foo.1.js'
renamed 'this_is_foucntion.js' -> 'this_is_foucntion.1.js'
renamed 'foo.1.js' -> 'foo.2.js'
renamed 'this_is_foo.1.js' -> 'this_is_foo.2.js'
renamed 'this_is_foucntion.1.js' -> 'this_is_foucntion.2.js'
renamed 'foo.2.js' -> 'foo.3.js'
renamed 'this_is_foo.2.js' -> 'this_is_foo.3.js'
renamed 'this_is_foucntion.2.js' -> 'this_is_foucntion.3.js'
renamed 'foo.3.js' -> 'foo.4.js'
renamed 'this_is_foo.3.js' -> 'this_is_foo.4.js'
renamed 'this_is_foucntion.3.js' -> 'this_is_foucntion.4.js'
renamed 'foo.4.js' -> 'foo.5.js'
renamed 'this_is_foo.4.js' -> 'this_is_foo.5.js'
renamed 'this_is_foucntion.4.js' -> 'this_is_foucntion.5.js'
```